# Java RegEx string excluding specific word

Tags: java, regex

The class **UpperCaseConverter** converts the input text into uppercase text excluding the word matched to regEx **"(?i)^((?!sht).)*"**.

What I expected to get is **1A0A-50-CRD-140-20002-063484C-N-01_Sht_1A.pdf** but the result is 
**1A0A-50-CRD-140-20002-063484C-N-01_Sht_1a.pdf**.

How could the last part of the letter be uppercase **except for the .pdf**

**UpperCaseConverter**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class UpperCaseConverter {

    private UpperCaseConverter(){};

    public static String convert(String text, String regEx) {
        StringBuilder toBeConverted = new StringBuilder(text);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toBeConverted);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            String buf = toBeConverted.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()).toUpperCase();
            toBeConverted.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), buf);
        }

        return toBeConverted.toString();
    }
}
```

---

***TestCase**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class UpperCaseConverterTest {

    @Test
    public void testUpperCase() {
        String expect = UpperCaseConverter.convert("1a0A-50-CRD-140-20002-063484C-N-01_Sht_1a.pdf", 
                "(?i)^((?!sht).)*");
        assertEquals("1A0A-50-CRD-140-20002-063484C-N-01_Sht_1A.pdf", expect);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `UpperCaseConverter`?

Comment: Without showing us any code there's not much to do but guess. Have you tried turning it off then on again?

Comment: it is a class i made to convert text in lowercase into uppercase excluding word matched to RegEx provided.

Comment: @JakeJeon what's wrong with `Matcher.appendReplacement` followed by `Matcher.appendTail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex stops just before the last occurrence of "sht", per your instruction. Only the regex'ed part gets an uppercase treatment.

Comment: You'd have to clarify the *purpose* of this regex. As it is, it works exactly as per your own specification "convert the input text into uppercase text excluding the word matched".